# How to make two HICON as one HICON? One on top of the other

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I'm trying to overlay a small pic on the other one under mfc.

Now i have two HICON(s) pointing to 2 pics.

How can i make them as one?

thanks.

Comment: Do you simply want to display them in the same position, or do you want to create a new icon that consists of the two icons merged?

Comment: Use an icon editor.  Or call DrawIcon() twice.

Comment: @HansPassant when i doing this with DrawIcon(), the result of 16x16 size icons is wrong. but DrawIconEx() is right. thank you!